# Relatively prime polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification

If $f(x)$ is relatively prime to $p(x)$ in $F[x]$ prove that there is a polynomial $g(x) \in F[x]$ such that $f(x)g(x) ≡ 1_F \pmod{ p(x)}$.

Now it has *just* occured to me that this is a field we are working in and not a ring because we are using an $F$. This is just an assumption, so I don't know if I am correct still. (I don't think it matters in the end.)

My attempt:

> Let $g(x)$ be a polynomial in $F(x)$. If $f(x)$ is relatively prime to $p(x)$ then there exists a polynomial $f(x)a(x) + b(x)p(x) = 1_F \mod p(x)$.
>
> But this means that $f(x)a(x) = 1_F \mod p(x)$. Let $a(x) = g(x)$. Done.

Comment: Done, after you have proved the existence of $a(x)$ and $b(x)$.

Comment: In your attempt, everything looks good except that the first equality shouldn't be modulo $p(x)$; it is just an equality.

Comment: @egreg then I have to essentially prove the division algorithm don't I? I don't know if I have time on that for a 10-minute quiz (it may possibly pop up on the quiz).

Comment: @Clayton $f(x) \cong f(x) \mod p(x)$. It's one of the congruence axioms.

Comment: @DonLarynx If that's given as known, then what you did is correct.

Comment: @egreg usually our quizzes have taken one minute to solve (seriously). If what is given as known? (the problem is complete here).

Comment: If the existence of $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ such that $f(x)a(x)+g(x)b(x)=h(x)$, where $h$ is a greatest common divisor of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, can be used, then you're done.

Comment: @DonLarynx: If you take your first equality (which is just a congruence), you are assuming what you are trying to prove. You must first have $f(x)a(x)+b(x)p(x)=1_F$. Now mod out by $p(x)$.

Comment: @Clayton, I see what you mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of an inverse of $f(x)$ modulo $p(x)$ is a direct consequence of the fact that, with the euclidean algorithm, one can prove

> for all $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in $F[x]$, there exists $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ such that $f(x)a(x)+g(x)b(x)=h(x)$, where $h(x)$ is a greatest common divisor of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

I use “a” because the greatest common divisor is determined up to a multiplicative constant. Saying that $f(x)$ and $p(x)$ are coprime means that $1$ is a greatest common divisor.

So you're correct, if the quoted theorem can be used in your test.